# I can't seem to insert data to my database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am having issues with my code when I try to insert data into my database, the section where it checks for matching username keeps popping up the error to select another username. I don't know what I am doing wrong, any help will be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
'Connecting to SQL Database and executing Query
Dim Strconn As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\phermacy.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"

Dim Strcmd As String = "INSERT INTO tblstaff_info(id,fname,lname,sex,nationality,status,dob,age,nationality,state,address,phone,email,dateemp,username,password) VALUES ('" & txtregid.Text & "','" & txtfname.Text & "','" & txtlname.Text & "','" & cmbstaffsex.Text & "','" & cmbstatus.Text & "','" & dtpickerdob.Text & "','" & txtage.Text & "','" & txtnationality.Text & "','" & txtstateofo.Text & "','" & rtbaddress.Text & "','" & txtphone.Text & "','" & txtemail.Text & "','" & dtpdateemp.Text & "','" & txtusername.Text & "','" & txtpassword.Text & "');"

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim sqlcmd As SqlCommand
sqlconn = New SqlConnection(Strconn)

Try
        sqlconn.Open()
Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Could not connect to DataBase. Application will close now!", vbCritical, "Database Error")
        End
End Try

sqlcmd = New SqlCommand(Strcmd, sqlconn)
da.SelectCommand = sqlcmd

sqlcmd.Dispose()
sqlconn.Close()

'Exception Handling-----------------------
Dim exc As Exception = Nothing

Try
        da.Fill(ds)
Catch ex As Exception
        exc = ex
Finally
        If Not (exc) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("User Name Already Exist. Please select a different User Name!", vbExclamation, "Already Exist")
            txtusername.Focus()
        Else
            MsgBox("Save info Successful.", vbInformation, "Successful")
            'Me.Close()
            'loginform.Show()
        End If
End Try
```

Comment: Have you heard of sql injections?

Comment: Did someone say Little Bobby Tables?

Comment: Yeah I have Ivan Starostin whats your suggestion please?

Comment: @GEORGESUTER what errors you are getting ? And following up what Ivan said, you should add sqlparameters and add to the command and then do an execute for preventing sql injection.

Comment: You also should not be storing user passwords in plain text. They should be salted and hashed. Another issue I see is you are storing age. That value is out of date as soon as you store it because it is calculated over time. You already have DOB, you should calculate age when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the connection's `.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `Pharmacy` - check your spelling!)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Pharmacy;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.